# Определение дня года на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дано целое число `k` `(1 k 365)`. Определить, каким будет `k`-й день года:
выходным (суббота и воскресенье) или рабочим, если 1 января — понедельник.
Мой код:

```
k = int(input("k = "))

if k % 7 == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5:
    print("Work")
elif k % 7 == 6 or 0 or 7:
    print ("Otdih")
```

Comment: If <k = int(input("k = ")) 
 
if k % 7 == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5: 
 print("Work") 
elif k % 7 == 6 or 0 or 7: 
 print ("Otdih")> много чего перепробовал но не смог через списки и k+=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неверная логика в условии.

Попробуйте исправить так:

```
k = int(input("k = "))

if (k - 1) % 7 < 5:
    print("Work")
else:
    print ("Otdih")
```

Объяснение: номера дней с 1 по 7 дают значение по модулю 7: `1,2,3,4,5,6,0`. Чтобы упростить условие отбора, сдвинем на 1 влево, получим  `0,1,2,3,4,5,6`. Для бОльших чисел этот же набор результатов повторяется

Answer (score 5):

Вот эта строчка

```
if k % 7 == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5:
```

не будет работать так, как вы ожидаете.
Ключевое слово 'or' разделяет отдельные логические выражения. А вовсе не варианты в рамках одного логического выражения.

То, что вы хотите, можно записать так:

```
if (1 <= (k % 7) <= 5):
```

или так:

```
if (k % 7) in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
```